# GWT: How to return (and handle) an error from multipart form (file) upload

Tags: java, javascript, gwt, servlets, file-upload

I have and **Google Web Toolkit (Multipart) Form** which post a file to my servlet. When error condition is happening in servlet I return an error. When everything is OK I return an JSON string.

```
    ...
    response.setContentType("text/html");
    response.setCharacterEncoding("UTF8");
    response.getWriter().write(out.toString());

} catch (FileUploadException e) {
    response.sendError(500, e.getMessage());
} catch (Exception e) {
    response.sendError(500, e.getMessage());
}
```

The problem is that I cant find a way to handle this in client side. This is the event that is fired when post goes OK and when error code is returned. But I can't find how to find is it OK or NOT? And how can I get an error message from Exception in client code?

```
@UiHandler("form")
void submitComplete(SubmitCompleteEvent event)
{
    ...
```

[image: Debug]

Comment: You *could* override the default error documents (in your server's configuration) so that they just output, for example, the status code - it would be easier to search for "500" in the response, then parse the whole default error page.

Comment: @Igor Klimer: Is it worth to change the server configuration for just one servlet? Why I can't find response code (200 or 500)?

Comment: Well, it *is* weird that you don't have access to the response code, like in `RequestBuilder`... But it seems nothing can be done for now (maybe create a new issue/improvement on GWT's bug tracker?) Two related threads from GWT's group: http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/cae1d99222fec795/65308c382ff86baa and http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/bfb422f1c6e9d0c3/c641b1369217e5ce. It seems it's important to set content-type of your response to `text/html` to ensure it works on all browsers (even if it actually contains JSON).

Comment: @Igor Klimer Thank you very much :) It seems that I have to return error messages with code 200 or change server configuration (or ignore everything returned from servlet that is not correct JSON)

Comment: Glad I could help :) I've added an answer summarizing the above comments, so that someone else could easier find the answer to this question.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Currently, there doesn't seem to be a suitable method available (like [`Response`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/http/client/Response.html)'s `getStatusCode`). You have to do with the error documents your server returns to you in [`SubmitCompleteEvent.getResults()`](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.0/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/FormPanel.SubmitCompleteEvent.html#getResults()). You can make this task easier by setting custom error documents on your server (which you should either way for your production server) that are easier to parse/handle.

Related threads on GWT's Google Group: [one](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/cae1d99222fec795/65308c382ff86baa) and [two](http://groups.google.com/group/google-web-toolkit/browse_thread/thread/bfb422f1c6e9d0c3/c641b1369217e5ce).